# Google ML Training task can't find module

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, gcloud, google-cloud-ml

I am trying to run my ml Python script using gcloud ml, but keep getting the error:

```
/usr/bin/python: No module named trainer
```

The command I am using is:

```
gcloud ai-platform jobs submit training "job6" --job-dir \
"gs://comp10001cards/root" --package-path "C:\\Users\hjstu\desktop" \             
 --module-name trainer.task --region "us-central1"
```

`"C:\\Users\hjstu\desktop"` contains a `__init__.py` file.
`"gs://comp10001cards/root"` contains the folder `trainer` which contains an `__init__.py` file and my script `task.py`.

Where is `/usr/bin/python`? What am I doing wrong? If it helps, I am using the `gcloud` tool from cmd within `C:\\Users\hjstu\desktop`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your trainer module and task.py script should sit locally on your computer when you run the `jobs submit training` command. The command will package your code, send it to the cloud, and execute it.

[image]

Have a look at the [relevant documentation page](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/tensorflow/packaging-trainer) for more information.

Comment: Is it possible to bundle a csv file into a training package? I have a csv file in the trainer directory in my project, but the code errors out when I try to run training because it is unable to find the csv file even though it's right there